# Importing Angular compiler to Bit results in dependency tree issues

Tags: angular, npm, bazel, bit.dev, dependency-tree

I am trying to implement one commons project where I keep several reusable Angular components and services, that I want to use for several other projects. I want to use Bit to share components (or rather modules) between my projects. I followed the instructions on [this](https://medium.com/swlh/develop-angular-re-usable-components-using-bit-382aeb0387d1) and other tutorials.

The following commands all worked fine and as expected:

*npm install bit-bin -g*

*bit login*

*bit init*

*bit add --main src/components/content/editable/editable.image.module.ts*

*bit status* prompts the following:

```
new components
(use "bit tag --all [version]" to lock a version with all your changes)

    > image ... ok
```

The trouble started when I wanted to import the Angular compiler to Bit, like so:

*bit import bit.envs/compilers/angular --compiler*

```
failed running npm install at /Users/SergDerbst/Development/tmt-patchbay/.git/bit/components/compilers/angular/bit.envs/10.1.7 with args: --production  
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @bit/bit.envs.compilers.angular@10.1.7
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=3.0.0 <4.0" from @bazel/typescript@2.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@bazel/typescript
npm ERR!   @bazel/typescript@"2.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/SergDerbst/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/SergDerbst/.npm/_logs/2021-07-05T06_56_37_358Z-debug.log
```

I am not too savvy with npm dependency handling, but apparently the compiler *@bit/bit.envs.compilers.angular@10.1.7* has TypeScript 4.0.3 as its dependency while Bazel demands an older version of TypeScript. Oddly enough, my own project has TypeScript 4.3.15 as devDependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "jest": "^27.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
},
"bit": {
    "env": {},
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm"
}
```

At first, I've tried older TypeScript versions or older versions of Angular on my project, but to no avail. I assume it has to do with the dependency tree of the Bit angular compiler itself. I could probably exclude Bazel as a dependency from it, but this should be necessary for Bit to atomize Angular modules. I tried to google the problem but couldn't find anyone else having this problem.

Maybe it is something obvious and stupid, that I have a blind spot for. Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you get this figured out?

Comment: Bit recently upgraded support for Angular. Please follow the updated docs - https://bit.dev/docs/frameworks/angular/angular-overview